# SQL Server object version control

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have got database deployment process which applies to production database. This process will change the definition of the store procedures/views/functions if they are not up to date with the current deployment. Problem is even though they are not changed deployment process will run ALTER step to make sure they are up to date. As we have got OLTP environment, during the deployment we get blocking on the stored procedures/functions.

What I want to implement is only alter the SP/view/function if the definition is changed.

We have already considered doing HashValue Compare of object definition (Does not work with large definition), date modified compare for object from system tables, SSDT, Redgate SQL Compare/Source Control.

Is there any other method which we can use to compare the definition during deployment and only apply the alter script if it is changed.

Thanks in advance for your input it this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the following script.
basically it creates a `Stored Procedure` that gets as a parameter an object name (SP/view/function) and an alter command for it. The stored procedure checks if the 'Alter' argument will change the existing object, and only if it will it will run it.

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[AlterDbObjectIfNecessary]    Script Date: 05/14/2014 09:28:30 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AlterDbObjectIfNecessary]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[AlterDbObjectIfNecessary]
GO



/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[AlterDbObjectIfNecessary]    Script Date: 05/14/2014 09:28:30 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- create new user-toolset relation/ toolset User
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AlterDbObjectIfNecessary]
    @alterCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @AlteredObjectname NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN


    DECLARE @objId INT
    DECLARE @objName NVARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @Def nvarchar(max)

    --Getting the ID of the object you want to alter
    SELECT
        @objId = id, @objName = o.name
    FROM sysobjects o 
    WHERE   o.type IN ('P', 'TR', 'V', 'TF', 'FN', 'IF')
            AND o.name = @AlteredObjectname


    --Getting the later definittion
    SELECT @Def = [definition]
    FROM sys.sql_modules 
    WHERE object_id = @objId


       --print @objName
       --print @def
       SET @def = REPLACE(@def, 'create PROC','alter PROC')
       SET @def = REPLACE(@def, 'create procedure','alter procedure')
       SET @def = REPLACE(@def, 'create function','alter function')
       SET @def = REPLACE(@def, 'create view','alter view')


    IF UPPER (@def) <> UPPER (@alterCommand)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY   
            --PRINT @alterCommand       
            --Alter the object to new definition
            EXEC sp_executesql @alterCommand
            PRINT @objName + ' Was Modified'
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH     
                PRINT 'Error. Failed to modify ' + @objName + ' : ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), ERROR_NUMBER()) + ' ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
        END CATCH
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'Modification was not required for ' +@objName
    END


END
GO
```

You can using it in the following manner:

```
DECLARE @alterCommand NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @AlteredObjectname NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @AlteredObjectname = 'MyObjectName' -- <Insert here the name of object you want to alter
SET @alterCommand = 'ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyObjectName]
-- The rest of the alter stattement    
 '
EXEC AlterDbObjectIfNecessary @AlteredObjectname, @alterCommand
```

Comment: It's Working like, As Expected

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage Schema Compare functionality of SSDT. Also when you publish database project in SSDT, it will generate a script only containing the difference.

Please take a look at an introduction video at http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Launch-2013/VS108

Comment: Appreciate your answer and link but unfortunately we do not want to user SSDT

Comment: Could you share why you don't use SSDT? Maybe other SSDT users can learn something from you.

Comment: In our current deployment process we do not use only change script and run the whole database deployment that is the reason i do not want to use SSDT and accomodate something which fits in our existing solution.